# What does the update to Windows 10 preserve from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I am eager to update to Windows 10 Technical Preview, for my Windows 7 has significantly slowed and Windows 8 is running out of space.

What is preserved when updating from Windows 7 to Windows 10 Technical Preview? (documents, program files?)

My attempts to research this have been unsuccessful. Or maybe I didn't dig deep enough.

Comment: Windows 7 to Windows 10 transfers everything.  All application data, application settings, and personal documents are transferred.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the update from Technical Preview to the original release will be also lossless?

Comment: Microsoft has already said they have plans for users of the technical beta to upgrade to the RTM obviuosly you still need a windows 10 license which isn't free for technical beta users I assume by original release you mean RTM